# How can I delete contents in a folder using a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, terminal

I would like to clear out my /bin folder in my project directory. How can I do this?

I tried `rm -rf ~/bin` but no luck

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should say "... my bin folder", not "my /bin folder".  `/bin` is an absolute path, `bin` is a relative path.

`rm -rf ~/bin` removes `$HOME/bin`, so not what you want either.

Now, it depends on where you are: if you are in your project directory when you type the command, just type `rm -rf bin`.

Comment: is ``-rf`` necessary? wouldn't ``rm ~/bin/*`` suffice

Answer (score 20):

~ is a shorthand to a current user home directory. So unless it's also your project directory you are doing something wrong. Other than that, clearing a directory would be

```
rm -rf ~/bin/*
```

And if you also want to clear the hidden files

```
rm -rf ~/bin/* ~/bin/.[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

**Make sure you are not doing**

```
rm -rf ~/bin/.*
```

especially as root as it will try to clear out your entire system.

**UPD**

Why? Since wildcard (`*`) is interpreted by shell as *zero or more characters of any kind* the `.*` will also match `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory), which will result in going all the way up and then down, trying to remove each file in your filesystem tree.

Answer (score 2):

`rm -rf ~/bin/{*,.[^.]*}`

would delete all files and directories in `~/bin/`, including hidden ones (name starts with `.`), but not the parent directory (i.e. `..`).

The `.[^.]*` matches all hidden files and directories whose name starts with a dot, the second char is NOT a dot, and with or without more chars.

Comment: Totally works for me. I was using `{*,.*}` but it shows an error message about directories `.`and `..`. The `.[^.]*` does the trick.